# How to match two consecutive new lines using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a problem that I seem unable to solve, with a Perl program I coded to parse a particular results file.

Its aim is to capture two values from a table embedded in a `.txt` results file, along with many other lines of information.

Since this table doesn't have a fixed number of lines in every file, the only way I found to try to parse it, is detecting the two consecutive newlines after the table and then go "backward" to capture the values of interest placed in the last line.

Here is the regex I'm using unsuccessfully and an example of the results table.

```
$_=~/([\d+\,]+)\s+([\d+\,]+\.\d+)\r\n\r\n/)
```

Table (values of interest in bold+italic):

| begin | 1,699,932 | 10,136.45 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,712,388 | 12,455.32 |
| 2 | 1,712,605 | 12,484.85 |
| 3 | ***1,712,611*** | ***12,513.51*** |

I tried several regex tools online where my regex matches correctly, but once incorporated into my code, it just doesn't work...

Example of reproducible code:

```
    #!usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;
    use Getopt::Long;
    
    my ($path);
    GetOptions(
        'path=s'          => \$path,
          );
        
    chdir $path or die "ERROR: Unable to enter $path: $!\n";
    opendir (TEMP , ".");
    my @files = readdir (TEMP);
    closedir TEMP;

for my $file (@files) {
    my $mAssize;
    my $qualAssize;

    if($file=~/(\w+)\_LRassembly.unicycler.log/){

          my$sample=$1;
          
          open(INFILE,"$file") or die ("ERROR: Unable to open Log to parse file $!\n");
          chomp(my @data = <INFILE>);

        for (@data) {
            
          if($_=~/([\d+\,]+)\s+([\d+\,]+\.\d+)\r\n\r\n/){
               
            print"Matched\n";
                    $mAssize=$1;
                    $qualAssize=$2;
                    print "MaxAssemblySize $mAssize\n";
                    print "QualAssembly $qualAssize\n";
            }
        }
         
        print OUT ("$sample\t$mAssize\t$qualAssize\n") or die ("ERROR: Unable to write log parsing file $!\n");
     
    }
  close INFILE;
}
```

Find attached an example of a full results file containing the table:
https://file.io/H8kCqE3gRov0

Sample of the output file:

```
    Polishing miniasm assembly with Racon (2023-07-08 00:32:20)
-----------------------------------------------------------
    Unicycler now uses Racon to polish the miniasm assembly. It does multiple rounds of polishing to get the best consensus. Circular unitigs are rotated between rounds such that all parts (including the ends) are polished well.

Saving to /storage/ONT/NETRAM_Campy/Filtered_reads/NKC1231_LRassembly/miniasm_assembly/racon_polish/polishing_reads.fastq:
  38,855 long reads

Polish       Assembly          Mapping
round            size          quality
begin       1,671,271        29,207.18
1           1,685,412        33,629.12
2           1,685,573        33,654.73
3           1,685,628        33,682.91

Best polish: /storage/ONT/NETRAM_Campy/Filtered_reads/NKC1231_LRassembly/miniasm_assembly/racon_polish/016_rotated.fasta
Saving /storage/ONT/NETRAM_Campy/Filtered_reads/NKC1231_LRassembly/miniasm_assembly/13_racon_polished.gfa
Saving /storage/ONT/NETRAM_Campy/Filtered_reads/NKC1231_LRassembly/003_racon_polished.gfa
```

The expected output would be ti print the following line (taking the result sample as guide):

| sample | Assembly | Mapping |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NKC1231 | 1,685,628 | 33,682.91 |

Comment: Each element of `@data` is a single line. So none could possibly contains two LF!

Comment: Yes I already noticed that, but I do not know how to solve that, because there are other lines I need to parse also, and those lines need to be individually processed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element of `@data` is a single line. So none could possibly contains two LF!

If you're going to read the file a line at a time, you will need to carry information from one pass to the next.

```perl
open( my $INFILE, "<", $file )           # Avoid globals, and always use 3-arg open
   or die( "ERROR: Can't open log file `$file`: $!\n" );  # Incl file name

my ( $found, $mAssize, $qualAssize );
while ( <$INFILE> ) {                    # No need to load entire file into mem.
   s/\s+\z//;  # Remove line endings. Handles both `\n` and `\r\n`.

   if ( $found && !length( $_ ) ) {
      print "Matched\n";
      print "MaxAssemblySize $mAssize\n";
      print "QualAssembly $qualAssize\n";
   }

   $found = ( $mAssize, $qualAssize ) = /([\d+\,]+)\s+([\d+\,]+\.\d+)\z/;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works smoothly. Thank you very much for the insight.